# the folder content could not be displayed input/output error

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ntfs, disk, budgie

I'm new to Linux and I have Ubuntu Budgie (Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS) (Budgie version: 10.6.1) (OS Type: 64-bit)

I have this ntfs type HDD:

[image: HDD]

I checked its file system:

[image: Checked file system]

I saw that it's not damaged:

[image: result of checking file system]

but when I mount it and go to some locations it shows this error:

> the folder content could not be displayed...input/output error

[image: Error message]

I can enter to this folder with terminal but when I run ls in it I got this error again:

[image: Error message in terminal]

I even can not copy it to somewhere else.
I have this error while accessing some other files for example a .`jpg` file when I trying to rename it.

I tried this:

1. Un-mounting & mounting the drive again.
2. Rebooting system.

Another partition work perfectly until now.
What I should do? I don't want to lose its content and I don't have enough space to backup it. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the output of `lsof /path/to/CascadiaCode.zip`? ... Do you have any antivirus service running on your system?

Answer (score 0):

`NTFS` files systems are *only* for windows. If you want to use your HDD in Ubuntu you should re-format it to be in `FAT`, for example.

Beware when formatting your drive though. All data will be deleted, so backup before doing anything.